# Does SolveForum abide by the CC BY-SA licence for StackExchange content?

Tags: copyright, creative-commons

I have noticed that SolveForum is replicating StackExchange questions, particularly their [Biology Forum](https://solveforum.com/forums/forums/biology.14/) which seems to be replicating the [Biology StackExchange questions](https://biology.stackexchange.com/) (but not answers).  While this is generally allowed under the Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 license under which content here is licensed, it does not seem like it is conforming to the requirements.  In particular:

- The big one is Share Alike.  I can find no reference that the content on SolveForum is licensed under CC BY-SA, and in the [Terms and rules](https://solveforum.com/forums/help/terms/) they say "You are granting us with a non-exclusive, permanent, irrevocable, unlimited license to use, publish, or re-publish your Content in connection with the Service".
- While they reference the screen name of the original author of the questions, they do not provide any other form of attribution, including a link back to the original content.  The [4.0 requirement for attribution](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/License_Versions#Detailed_attribution_comparison_chart) includes "To the extent practicable, URI or link to the material if supplied".

Does the use of the StackExchange content on SolveForum meet the requirements of CC BY-SA licence?  Is there another way that what they are doing is not breach of copyright?

Comment: I think you've answered the question yourself: the use of the material does not seem to meet the CC BY-SA 4.0 Attribution and ShareAlike conditions. Not sure what could be added there. Such scraping is certainly not “fair use”. Note that such Stack Exchange pirate sites are *extremely* common. They are just hoping to get some Google ranking in order to get ad impressions. These are absolute bottom-feeders of the content ecosystem, maybe only surpassed by those Youtube channels that scrape Reddit posts and turn them into videos with automated text-to-speech.